# Subcriber getting multiiple notifications for new comments

Tags: comments

This the email i received from a subscriber, i am not sure how to prevent multiple emails from going out.I do not use a plugin just the WordPress native comment mamagent

“Notify me when new comments are added” checkbox and
now each time a comment is added I get four e-mails with the same comment.
Is there any way you can remove people from that service?

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be useful to determine *why* the extra notifications are sent (forwarding settings?), there is a way to adjust who gets notification emails when a comment is posted (which is what you asked, not how to fix the problem):

```
// adds emails to the 'notify admins on comment submit'
// from http://www.sourcexpress.com/customize-wordpress-comment-notification-emails/
// must be enabled via Settings, Discussion, "Email me whenever Anyone posts a comment" 


function ss_comment_moderation_recipients( $emails, $comment_id ) {
    // Email notification only to the admin
    $emails = array( get_option( 'admin_email' ) );
    $emails[] = "anotherperson@example.com";
    $emails[] = "morepeople@example.com";
return $emails;
}

add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'ss_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'ss_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
```

The $emails array is an array of emails to send to. The code above gets the admin_email email address, then adds two emails to it. The two add_filters are needed to ensure it works.

Based on the answer here: http://www.sourcexpress.com/customize-wordpress-comment-notification-emails/